# Pysprk 3.1.1 Py4JavaError

Tags: java, ubuntu, pyspark

I'm running pyspark 3.1.1 with java openjdk 11.0.11 on my Ubuntu machine. I have created some random data in a dataframe using

```
import numpy as np
n, p = (10, 4)
data = np.random.rand(n, p)

# create the dataframe
schem = StructType([StructField('col_%d'%i, FloatType(), False) for i in range(p)])
randData = spark.createDataFrame(data.tolist(), schema=schem)
randData.show()
```

This works perfectly fine on my Windows 10 machine with pyspark 3.0.1, but on the above-mentioned system, I get this stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-6f093bb5efc1> in <module>
      7 # create the dataframe
      8 randData = spark.createDataFrame(data.tolist(), schema=schem)
----> 9 randData.show()

~/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    482         """
    483         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 484             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    485         else:
    486             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

~/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

~/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o221.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 34.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 34.0 (TID 619) (192.168.150.128 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Bad data in pyspark.daemon's standard output. Invalid port number:
  458961458 (0x1b5b3232)
Python command to execute the daemon was:
  ipython3 -m pyspark.daemon
Check that you don't have any unexpected modules or libraries in
your PYTHONPATH:
  /home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:/home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:/home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python:
Also, check if you have a sitecustomize.py module in your python path,
or in your python installation, that is printing to standard output
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2253)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2202)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2201)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2201)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1078)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2440)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2382)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2371)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2202)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2223)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:472)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2722)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3687)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3685)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2722)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2929)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:338)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Bad data in pyspark.daemon's standard output. Invalid port number:
  458961458 (0x1b5b3232)
Python command to execute the daemon was:
  ipython3 -m pyspark.daemon
Check that you don't have any unexpected modules or libraries in
your PYTHONPATH:
  /home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:/home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:/home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python:
Also, check if you have a sitecustomize.py module in your python path,
or in your python installation, that is printing to standard output
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

I get the same kind of stack trace with this simple command:

`spark.CreateDataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], ['a', 'b', 'c']).show()`.

Any idea what's going on with this?

I installed pyspark using the download from spark.apache.org. `JAVA_HOME` is set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`. I have the following set in my bashrc:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/ahowe42/anaconda3/bin
export SPARK_HOME=/home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=ipython3
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$SPARK_HOME/python
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PYTHONPATH:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
```

I load and initialize pyspark using

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *#avg, count, expr
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
spark.sparkContext.appName = 'exploreReadWrite'
spark
```

Comment: How did you install pyspark? Did you use `pip` or did you download Spark from spark.apache.org? And could you please add the exact command line that you use to start the Spark code?

Comment: I updated the question with this information.

Comment: You have set `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` but in the top you write you are using openjdk 11.x. Maybe changing `JAVA_HOME` to the 11 JDK can help?

Comment: Good catch. Corrected JAVA_HOME, but no change in behavior.

Comment: I have noticed that `echo $PYTHONPATH` returns `/home/ahowe42/anaconda3/bin:/home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python`  as expected, but the stack trace says it is `/home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:/home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:/home/ahowe42/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python:`. Perhaps this is the issue as the error says, any idea where this is changed after I set it in my .bashrc scrip?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment, but I don't have the rep to comment yet.
Have you tried `which python`? Similar errors for spark port numbers refer to python version mismatches between libraries. With regard to your `$PYTHONPATH`, this will be set in multiple places, it can be updated by any of the processes invoked by your shell - so you know that it's been altered from the string in your `.bashrc` by your server. However, `$PYTHONPATH` will be searched left to right, I think, so if there is a python runtime in your anaconda directory, I think it will be invoked before the spark version, if you just say `py`. Could it be that your anaconda version and spark version are using different versions of python?

Comment: `Which python` and `which ipython3` both point to my anaconda directory as expected, and spark is set to use ipython3, so this seems ok. There isn't actually a python installation in the spark folder, as far as I can see.

Answer (score -1):

On my Ubuntu, I install Spark and Hadoop separately

```
sudo apt install python3-pip openjdk-11-jdk # install Java, pip
pip3 install pyspark # install PySpark

# download and extract Hadoop 3.2.2
wget https://downloads.apache.org/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.2.2/hadoop-3.2.2.tar.gz
unzip hadoop-3.2.2.tar.gz

# setup environment variables
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="hadoop-3.2.2/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*"

# run Python
python3
```

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .master('local[*]')
    .appName('SO')
    .getOrCreate()
)
# <pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession object at 0x10f9e7220>

spark.createDataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], ['a', 'b', 'c']).show()
+---+---+---+                                                                   
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  4|  5|  6|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm on Ubuntu - not a Mac OS, and describing your different installation doesn't help answer the question.

Comment: I just updated to Ubuntu instruction, it's basically the same. Maybe you can give it a try?

Comment: I already have installed pyspark+hadoop using the installer provided by Apache. Your solution isn't targeting anything, just simply saying "try installing another way". This does not help me figure out and solve the actual, specific problem.

Comment: Well, it's up to you, but try installing another way and if it works, it might give you a clue why the current installing does not work.